# Perl: references of enumerated lists

Tags: perl

I'm reading "Perl 5 Tutorial by Chan Bernard Ki Hong. He states...

> Be careful of enumerated lists as a special case! As indicated on the perlref manpage, taking a reference of an enumerated list evaluates to a list of references of the list elements.

I'm not sure what the difference between an "enumerated list" and an "array" is.

He gives a reference example for an array:

```
$arrayref = \@array;
```

And one for an enumerated list:

```
@list = \($a, $b, $c); # Actually (\$a, \$b, \$c)
```

The enumerated list, ($a, $b, $c), looks like an array to me. What am I not seeing here?

So if `@array = ($a, $b, $c)`, and `$arrayref = \@array`, then wouldn't `@$array` be `($a, $b, $c)?`

Comment: [FAQ: What is the difference between a list and an array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array%3f)

Comment: That tutorial is pretty old (published 2003). It doesn't even mention `use strict;` until page 160, and that should be at the top of every Perl script you ever write. You might want to find a [more modern tutorial](http://perl-tutorial.org/#index3h1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In perl, arrays are variable types, never a type of value.  You can think of an array as the type of variable that stores a list as a value, but arrays and lists are otherwise quite distinct concepts.  `($a,$b,$c)` is a list (supposing it is in list context; in scalar context, it is the single value `$c`), not an array.

Normally, you use \ on variables (or at least lvalue scalars, as in \$hash{key}); the tutorial you are reading is just warning about the special case where \ is used on a list value or a slice: `\($a,$b,$c)` is equivalent to `(\$a,\$b,\$c)`.  `\@array` on the other hand simply produces a reference to the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would think of it as "a list is a constant array":

```
@array = ("list item 1", "list item 2", "list item 3");
```

You can't do something like:

```
("list item 1", "list item 2", "list item 3")[1] = "list item 2a";
```

because you can't change a constant, but you could do:

```
$array[1] = "list item 2a";
```

because you copied the list into an array above and now it's a variable.

In your example, yes, they are all really arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $a = 1;
my $b = 2;
my $c = 3;

# copy a list into an array
my @array = ($a, $b, $c);

# create a reference to an arrayr
my $arrayref = \@array;

# copy a list of variable references into an array
my @list = \($a, $b, $c);

print "before:\n";
for (my $i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {
print "array[$i]: $array[$i]\n";
print "arrayref[$i]: $arrayref->[$i]\n";
print "list[$i]: ${$list[$i]}\n";
}

$array[1] = "2a";
$arrayref->[1] = "2a";
# ok, really a reference to a constant, which shouldn't be mixed in
# with references to variables, but for simplicity...
$list[1] = \"2a";

print "\nafter:\n";
for (my $i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {
print "array[$i]: $array[$i]\n";
print "arrayref[$i]: $arrayref->[$i]\n";
print "list[$i]: ${$list[$i]}\n";
}

exit 0;
```

output:

```
before:
array[0]: 1
arrayref[0]: 1
list[0]: 1
array[1]: 2
arrayref[1]: 2
list[1]: 2
array[2]: 3
arrayref[2]: 3
list[2]: 3

after:
array[0]: 1
arrayref[0]: 1
list[0]: 1
array[1]: 2a
arrayref[1]: 2a
list[1]: 2a
array[2]: 3
arrayref[2]: 3
list[2]: 3
```